# Cross-Platform Installer paths

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, platform

I'm writing an installer for a Python app I'm making, and needed to have paths for different file locations. These are what I have so far, and so wondered if these were correct of if I should change any of them (particularly the Linux/macOS ones)

I have a path for:

- the actual binary
- for the config file
- the README
- the start menu, should the user want to add a shortcut (this will create the `.desktop` file on Linux/macOS, a shortcut on Windows)
- the desktop, should the user want to add a shortcut

Can anyone let me know if there should be changes to these to make them work on all devices etc

### Windows

```
binary = '%ProgramFiles%'
configs = '%AppData%'
README = '%ProgramFiles%'
start menu = '%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu'
desktop = os.path.expanduser('~\Desktop')
```

### Linux

```
binary = '/usr/local/bin'
config = os.path.expanduser('~/.config')
README = '/usr/local/share/doc/packages'
start menu = os.path.expanduser('~/.local/share/applications')
desktop = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
```

### macOS

```
binary = '/usr/local/bin'
config = os.path.expanduser('~/.config')
README = '/usr/local/share/doc/packages'
start menu = os.path.expanduser('~/.local/share/applications')
desktop = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have added the option for the user to change the paths anyway so it doesn't have to be perfect but I would like the best 'normal' paths

Comment: If you let the user edit the paths, you should probably check that the user has sufficient privileges to write there abd warn if they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use `sysconfig` as much as possible.
For example on a POSIX system `get_paths()` returns:

```
In [5]: sysconfig.get_paths()
Out[5]: 
{'stdlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 'platstdlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 'purelib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 'platlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 'include': '/usr/local/include/python3.9',
 'platinclude': '/usr/local/include/python3.9',
 'scripts': '/usr/local/bin',
 'data': '/usr/local'}
```

Note that sysconfig supports different schemes:

```
In [6]: sysconfig.get_scheme_names()
Out[6]: 
('nt',
 'nt_user',
 'osx_framework_user',
 'posix_home',
 'posix_prefix',
 'posix_user')
```

The `home` or `user` schemes are handy when the installer doesn't have root or administrator privileges.

Comment: Are you saying to use `sysconfig` to determine normal paths when coding or use it in the script?

Comment: I was thinking about the installer, but there is no reason you couldn't use it in the program itself.

Comment: Yes I meant the installer by script, will take a look